# django custom widget

Tags: python, django

Добрый день!В forms.py у `ChoiceField(choices=((1, Значение1),(2, Значение2),....))`  в html -> `<select......><option value=1>Значение1<.....`мне нужно добавить атрибут и передавать в него уникальное значение возможно ли так сделать, в документации описаны примеры по добавлению статических атрибутов.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#Select
Вот ваш виджет, посмотрите как он работает, как в шаблоне строится. Может вы создадите новый виджет отнаследуясь от этого, может переоприделите шаблон, передав динамические атрибуты совместно с choices. Варианты есть и если вы решите эту задачу, то получите хорошие знания :)